# Oracle EXECUTE IMMEDIATE Not doing what expected in stored procedure

Tags: oracle

I have a stored procedure which has several checks in them however the following section gives me problems with the execute immediate

for example when I try to compile the procedure with the below statements it complains that table or view does not exist.

```
...
...
...
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE mytable(col1 number, col2 number, col3 number)';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO mytable (col1,col2,col3)
   SELECT a,b,c FROM source_table' ;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO c FROM mytable;
```

6:18:22  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  {50:29} PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

However,

If I remove the

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO c FROM mytable;

It compiles and works.

Please advise on what is probably a very simple colution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When Oracle compiles the stored procedure, it checks for the existence of `mytable`. If `mytable` doesn't exist at compilation time, it will give you an error.

Your options:

1. Create the table ahead of time.
2. You are stuck performing your `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` using dynamic SQL (`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`) like you are already doing for the `INSERT` statement.

Note that, if you decide to go with the 2nd option, it is possible to assign the result of the query to your `c` variable, like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable' INTO c;
```

However, it's generally not a good idea to mix DDL statements with queries in your stored procedures, because:

1. It forces you down the path of dynamic SQL, which can easily break.
2. You can't write a proper transactional stored procedure, because every DDL statement performs an implicit `commit`.

Comment: In our stored SP-creation scripts we create & drop required tables specifically to eliminate the need for this kind of dynamic SQL.